# Targeted Time Zones List / Options

Tags: timezone

The existing code that I am working with provides a drop-down for the end 
user to select a time zone.

My goal is to limit the choices down to
1. America
and
a. Option Eastern 
value America/New_York
b. Option Central
value America/Chicago
c. Option Mountain DST
value America/Denver
d. Option Mountain no DST
value America/Phoenix
e. Option Pacific
value America/Los_Angeles

Narrowing it down to America was easy enough by simply commenting out the code.
Narrowing it down further to the 5 time zones is turning out to be beyond my pay grade.

Any advice?

```
$regions = [
#   'Africa'     => DateTimeZone::AFRICA,
    'America'    => DateTimeZone::AMERICA,
#   'Antarctica' => DateTimeZone::ANTARCTICA,
#   'Aisa'       => DateTimeZone::ASIA,
#   'Atlantic'   => DateTimeZone::ATLANTIC,
#   'Europe'     => DateTimeZone::EUROPE,
#   'Indian'     => DateTimeZone::INDIAN,
#   'Pacific'    => DateTimeZone::PACIFIC
];

$timezones = [];
foreach ($regions as $name => $mask) {
    $zones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers($mask);
    foreach ($zones as $timezone) {
        $timezones[$name][$timezone] = $timezone;
    }
}

$actualTimezone = JFactory::getSession()->get('user-timezone', $displayData['dateHelper']->getDate()->getTimezone()->getName(), 'Calendar');
?>
<form action="<?php echo JUri::base(); ?>" method="get" class="dp-timezone dp-form">
    <span class="dp-timezone__label">
        <?php echo $displayData['translator']->translate('COM_CALENDAR_CHOOSE_TIMEZONE'); ?>:
    </span>
    <select name="tz" class="dp-select dp-timezone__select">
        <option value="UTC"<?php $actualTimezone == 'UTC' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>
            <?php echo $displayData['translator']->translate('JLIB_FORM_VALUE_TIMEZONE_UTC'); ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach ($timezones as $region => $list) { ?>
            <?php foreach ($list as $timezone => $name) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $timezone; ?>"<?php echo $actualTimezone == $timezone ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>
                    <?php echo $displayData['translator']->translate($name); ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="profile.tz" class="dp-input dp-input-hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_calendar" class="dp-input dp-input-hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="profile" class="dp-input dp-input-hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode(JUri::getInstance()->toString()); ?>" class="dp-input dp-input-hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: Seems like you know the time zones you want, why not just hard code those ones?  Also, if you want all US states, don't forget about Hawaii (`Pacific/Honolulu`) and Alaska (`America/Anchorage` and `America/Adak`).

Comment: The list gets bigger if you want to include US Territories as well:  American Samoa (`Pacific/Pago_Pago`), Guam (`Pacific/Guam`), the Northern Mariana Islands (`Pacific/Saipan`), Puerto Rico (`America/Puerto_Rico`) and the U.S. Virgin Islands (`America/St_Thomas`).

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes, I know the zones I want. And yes, I know the list can be big.

I am working with 1) Joomla, and 2) an existing app. I may or may not completely rewrite the other work. Or, I will discover a simpler solution with a few mods to the existing platform.